# Short circuit evaluation in CASE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Can somebody please explain what is happening here and why?

```sql
select case when y = 0 then -1 else sum(1/y) end
from (select 0 y group by y) x
group by y
```

This query produces division by zero error, even though CASE explicitly checks for 0. Pay no attention to the fact that the query is meaningless and uses constants; I have tried to create a minimal example. It looks like the query planner decides to evaluate aggregation function before checking WHEN clause, but why? And is there a way to force it to short circuit? The only workaround I have found yet is to use `sum(1/nullif(y, 0))`, which is then discarded anyway upon evaluation of WHEN.

Comment: Is the other form of case ie `case y when 0 then …` any different?

Comment: It gives the same result. In fact I think they are equivalent in terms of the syntax tree.

Comment: This *might* work: `case when y = 0 then -1 else sum(1/case when y=0 then null else y end) end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Working As Designed™](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL):

> When it is essential to force evaluation order, a `CASE` construct (see Section 9.18) can be used. [...]
>
> `CASE` is not a cure-all for such issues, however. One limitation of the technique illustrated above is that it does not prevent early evaluation of constant subexpressions. As described in Section 38.7, functions and operators marked `IMMUTABLE` can be evaluated when the query is planned rather than when it is executed. Thus for example
>
> ```
> SELECT CASE WHEN x > 0 THEN x ELSE 1/0 END FROM tab;
> ```
>
> is likely to result in a division-by-zero failure due to the planner trying to simplify the constant subexpression, even if every row in the table has x > 0 so that the `ELSE` arm would never be entered at run time.

In your (obviously contrived) example the value of `y` is known at the query compilation time, so `1/y` causes the division by zero error before the query is executed.

If you try to avoid the immutability using something like this, for example:

```sql
with t (r) as (values (random()::int) ) 
select case when y = 0 then -1 else sum(1/y) end 
from (select r y from t ) x 
group by y;
```

you will hit another caveat, though only half of the time, because in this case division by zero will be happening at run time:

> Another limitation of the same kind is that a `CASE` cannot prevent evaluation of an aggregate expression contained within it, because aggregate expressions are computed before other expressions in a `SELECT` list or `HAVING` clause are considered.

Comment: There were no constants in my original query where I stumbled upon this. Zero was produced by an aggregate in one of the inner queries. Your second point does explain this behaviour, although I am still not sure this is such a good design after all. In the document they suggest to filter out rows with 0, but in some cases, especially in math and statistics, you just have to treat them as degenerate cases, which is what CASE-WHEN construct was supposed to emulate. Thanks!

Comment: @NebehrGudahtt SQL is not a procedural language, and the idea of "execution order" is alien to it.